# How to Handle Memory for readonly property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have following property in one of my class

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableArray *children;
```

And I have following method to allocate memory to this property.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)children {
    if (!children) {
        children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    }

    return children;
}
```

When I run the profiler in the xcode it shows I have memory leak in the above method. I'm confused about releasing memory in such situation.
Is it ok if I use it with autorelase as follows.

```
children = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1] autorelease];
```

can some one pls help me to solve this.

Comment: does the memory leak warning go away if you create "`children`" in your class's "`init`" or "`viewDidLoad`" method (the latter, if it's a view controller)?

Comment: are you compiling with ARC? (i'm assuming not, but just to be sure...)

Comment: @Micheal I didn't try that yet. And its not a view controller

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "profiler"? The Leaks instrument? Also, is this the only leak? Perhaps an instance of the class that this code is from has leaked and the leak of this array is secondary to that. Finally, the Leaks instrument shows you were a block of memory that has been leaked was allocated. It doesn't show you where it was leaked. If some other code obtained the `children` array and over-retained it or under-released it, then that code is responsible for the leak of the object allocated here. You have to examine the retain/release history of a given object to see what happened.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. @Micheal yes it's the leak instrument provide by the xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Do you release the children in your dealloc? If not, thats your problem!

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [children release];
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: I have released it in the dealloc

Comment: Ok, then your code is perfectly fine. Autorelease is not the solution, it will make things worse. Your leak is somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you let the compiler do the work for you? You could do the following:

```
- (id) init {
if(self=[super init]) {
    children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
}
```

Use the dealloc iTukker showed you and make the property synthesized.

At least for me this is far more straightforward.

Comment: I hope the profiler gives me wrong information. As it seems error is should be somewhere else. Thanks for your help